# Should the git-archive command also run filters?

Tags: git

I just noticed that `git archive` also runs my filters in `.gitattributes`. Is this documented behaviour? (I don't see it in the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).)

**Details**

As an exercise I have written a filter which smudges by inserting into `*.tex` files the information from `git describe --tags HEAD` (no this code is not at all useful) in the form

```
\setGitVersion{<tag>}
```

and cleans by changing that to

```
\setGitVersion{}
```

(basically an exercise in coding my own keyword substitution). I just noticed however that if I run `git archive` on the repository, the archived file includes the smudged version of `*.tex` files rather than the clean version.

*Remark*: because regardless of which commit I specify for the archive, the tag displayed is always the info from `git describe --tags HEAD`, I can conclude that git is taking the files from the repo and sending it through my (broken) filter before archiving it.

**Question**

Is the the expected behaviour? If so, is it documented somewhere and can I count on it behaving like this in the future (in which case I need to be much more careful with filters). If not, is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is expected behaviour. Archiving executes filters stored in gitattributes.

It's not particularly well documented but there is a section under [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) on creating an archive.

> If the attribute `export-subst` is set for a file then Git will expand several placeholders when adding this file to an archive. The expansion depends on the availability of a commit ID, i.e., if [git-archive[1]](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) has been given a tree instead of a commit or a tag then no replacement will be done. The placeholders are the same as those for the option `--pretty=format`: of [git-log[1]](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), except that they need to be wrapped like this: `$Format:PLACEHOLDERS$` in the file. E.g. the string `$Format:%H$` will be replaced by the commit hash.

I wouldn't expect this behaviour to go away in the future as it's relevant and often necessary functionality.